# Why Safari produces giant videos compared to Chrome, when using the MediaDevices.getUserMedia() API?

Tags: javascript, safari, webrtc, html5-video, video-capture

I was setting up a little experiment to measure the size of the videos captured by the [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) API.

When I was running my code in Safari it produces 5-10 times larger videos than in Chrome. Here is my code:

`index.html:`

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Video Spike</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video autoplay id="video" muted></video>
    <br />
    <button id="record">Record 10 second video</button>
  </body>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```

`index.js:`

```js
const videoElem = document.getElementById("video");
const recordBtn = document.getElementById("record");

async function startCamera() {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: {
      frameRate: 30,
      height: 240,
      width: 240,
    },
  });

  videoElem.srcObject = stream;

  let buffer;

  recordBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    buffer = [];
    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    setTimeout(() => recorder.stop(), 10000);

    recorder.ondataavailable = async (event) => {
      buffer.push(event.data);
      console.log(
        "current video size:",
        new Blob(buffer, { type: "video/webm" }).size / 1024 / 1024,
        "MB"
      );
    };

    recorder.start(1000);
  });
}

startCamera();
```

After 10 seconds, this logs 6.5MB for Safari, and 0.6MB for Chrome for me.

I tried to play around with the MediaContraints object, resolutions and recorded durations but it seem to always have this huge size difference between the two browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option to set the `bitsPerSecond` when creating a `MediaRecorder`.

```
new MediaRecorder(stream, { bitsPerSecond: 200_000 });
```

Looks like Chrome and Safari have different default values.

There is also a possibility to set the `audioBitsPerSecond` and `videoBitsPerSecond` separately.

Comment: Interesting. That solves the issue indeed, thank you!

Comment: For anyone needing this in the future, the provided value in the example won't work as it needs to be an integer. Remove the underscore and all will be good.

Comment: The underscore is called a "Numeric separator". It's meant to make number literals more readable. It should be supported by any modern JavaScript runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue is actually that Safari does encode your video as H264 in an mp4 container, while Chrome does produce a VP9 webm video.

Setting `{ type: "video/webm" }` in the `Blob()` constructor isn't enough to make it an actual webm file. For this you must set the `MediaRecorder`'s `mimeType`:

```js
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: "video/webm" });
```

Note that you can even control the codecs being used. But unfortunately Safari still doesn't support anything else than H264 in mp4.

So , while it's true that Safari has a significantly higher `videoBitsPerSecond` default value (10Mbps vs 2.5Mbps in Chrome) and that you can reduce it as proposed by the other answer, you'll still get a huge difference between both browsers, for instance using your test-case and forcing a 2.5Mbps video bit rate, my Safari produces a 3MB file, while Chrome produces a 0.8Mb one. And there is not much you can do to it.